# Operational error no such column SQLite 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I've struggled with this for long. I can only get query results from the first column, all the other columns return  "No such column" What could be the problem. I'm new to python and sqlite3...

```
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS learner_data(ADM INT NOT NULL,NAME TEXT NOT NULL,CLASS TEXT NOT NULL,STREAM TEXT NOT NULL,CATEGORY TEXT NOT NULL,GENDER TEXT NOT NULL,COUNTY TEXT NOT NULL,PARENT TEXT NOT NULL,PARENT_CONTACT TEXT NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(CLASS,STREAM,CATEGORY,NAME,ADM))''')
```

Select failing:

```
SELECT * FROM learner_data WHERE CLASS is FORM_II
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't SHOUT. Your title will automatically be formatted as a title.

Comment: What is your query?

Comment: SELECT * FROM learner_data WHERE CLASS is FORM_II

Comment: SELECT * FROM learner_data WHERE ADM is 300 => Only this gives me an answer, all the others give errors.

Comment: Your queries are incorrect.  Please create an example of your database with some sample data and expected results.

Comment: This is wrong:
SELECT * FROM learner_data WHERE CLASS is FORM_II
Correct:
SELECT * FROM learner_data WHERE CLASS = 'FORM_II'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment: `...WHERE CLASS is FORM_II...`

You cannot use `is` here, you should use `=`. And, not quoting `FORM_II` means that you're trying to find rows where the value is the same for the columns `CLASS` and `FORM_II` (but the latter isn't a column so this will always render 0 matches), instead of looking for the *value* `FORM_II`.

So, try `SELECT * FROM learner_data WHERE CLASS = 'FORM_II'`

Comment: Thank you  much, I've made it with this help you've given...I appreciate

Comment: Actually the "FORM_II" is coming from QComboBox dropdown,meaning there are other options apart from it.How do I quote it from the combobox?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about, sorry. I have never heard about QComboBox. Maybe you could ask another question.

Comment: This is for Python's PyQt5

Answer (score 0):

```
def fetch_learner_data_from_combo(self):
    new = str("self.stream_combo.currentText()")
    connection= sqlite3.connect("mydb.db")
    query = ("SELECT * FROM learner_data WHERE STREAM =   new")
    result = connection.execute(query)
    self.marks_table.setRowCount(0)

    for row_number,row_data in enumerate(result):
        self.marks_table.insertRow(row_number)
        for column_number,data in enumerate(row_data):
            self.marks_table.setItem(row_number,column_number,QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```